# Determine file type in C

Tags: c, file, file-type

I am working on a program in C on a linux machine that displays the file type of a file presented as an argument to the program. The program needs to determine if a file is any one of the following: directory, device, (regular) file, link, socket, or fifo. I am not exactly sure how to determine file type.

Here is my code thus far (not much):

```
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if( argc == 1 )     /* default: current directory */
        puts("Directory");
    else
        while( --argc > 0 )
            determine_ftype(*++argv);

    return  0;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the POSIX `stat` function and read the `st_mode` field of the structure `struct stat` returned by the function.

`stat` function:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/stat.html

The structure `struct stat` type:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sysstat.h.html

For glibc, you can also read the section `14.9.3 Testing the Type of a File` of the `glibc` manual:

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Testing-File-Type.html

Comment: So, basically I will use st_mode and go through a series of if statements to determine what the file type is. Correct?