# How to find file type(format) without extension file using c program?

Tags: c

I have the image, txt file without extension. They are,

flower (image)

simple (txt)

I need to find file format for the above files using c.
currently i am working in linux.
Any one help me.

```
/* This program used to find the file format for without extention  file */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <error.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
FILE *fp;
struct image image_bmp; 

if (argc != 2) {
    perror("Error in commandline argument\n");
    exit(1);
}

fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
if (fp == NULL)
    error(1, errno, "Error in file open\n");

/* i am try to display argv[1] file format for without extention file
Ex: argv[1] is a txt file
    argv[2] is a image file
*/

fclose(fp);
    error(1, errno, "Error in file close\n");

return 0;
}
```

i know file command is solve this problem. But i am trying using c.

Comment: tokenize and check the last token (in general)...

Comment: i am not saying about tokenize the file name.(with extension file is done). But how to find the file type without extension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine file type in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276521/determine-file-type-in-c)

Comment: @user1314742: I don't think that's quite the right duplicate - it's more about using `stat` to tell if something is a file/directory/link/whatever, rather than determining its internal file format, like `file` does.

Comment: @PaulR you are right, I haven't pay much attention to that. Thanx .  I m removing the comment (unfortunately I could not remove my flag)

Comment: @user1314742: Don't worry about your dupe flag: the question will probably be put on hold shortly anyway for being too broad.

Comment: There's a cross-platform (Windows/Linux) library called [TrID](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) which might be useful for this task.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`popen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) to run the [`file`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) command, e.g.:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char cmd[PATH_MAX];
    char result[PATH_MAX];
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        FILE *fp = NULL;

        sprintf(cmd, "file '%s'", argv[i]);
        fp = popen(cmd, "r");
        if (fp == NULL)
        {
            perror("popen");
        }
        else
        {
            fgets(result, PATH_MAX, fp);
            pclose(fp);
            fputs(result, stdout);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This works on pretty much any *nix-like OS (Linux, Mac OS X, FreeBSD, Solaris, etc).

Compile and run:

```
$ gcc -Wall popen_file.c
$ ./a.out a.out
a.out: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
$ ./a.out foo
foo: directory
$ ./a.out chart
chart: PNG image data, 1249 x 961, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
```

Comment: Thank you. I am try to implement the file command. so please help me for how to find the file type without extension in c.(I done the file command for image using header format, now i am trying to support txt, elf, audio)

Comment: What is it about the above example that doesn't answer your question ?

Comment: @PaulR as he already said, he wants to implement it himself in C and not just use an external program to pipe info from.

Comment: @pfannkuchen_gesicht: if you look at the edit history you'll see he didn't specify that originally. Even now the question is not entirely clear.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`libmagic`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/libmagic.3.html) library (on Ubuntu, install `libmagic-dev` for headers). This is the library that also backs the `file` command; instead of using `popen` to run the `file` command you should use this library directly.

The following code shows an example on how to detect the file type of a named file (please note that error checking is omitted from function calls other than the `magic_file` call:

```
#include <magic.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // open the magic library, with MAGIC_MIME_TYPE flag
    // so that the mime type of the file is returned instead
    // of human readable information
    magic_t m = magic_open(MAGIC_MIME_TYPE);

    // load the default database
    magic_load(m, NULL);

    // detect the mime type of a file named `a_file_without_extension`
    const char *type = magic_file(m, "a_file_without_extension");
    if (type) {
        printf("The recognized type is %s\n", type);
    }
    else {
        printf("An error occurred: %s\n", magic_error(m));
    }

    // close the database; in a long-running program you wouldn't
    // need to close the handle all the time.
    magic_close(m);
}
```

Prints out the mime type of the file named `a_file_without_extension`; e.g. say:

```
The recognized type is image/png
```

Comment: Using the library directly is better in some ways of course, but less portable (Linux only ?).

Comment: @PaulR it is exactly as portable as using the `file` command, e.g. Linux, BSD, Unix. MacOSX has a different `file` command and it could give different output as well.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I am try to implement the file command. so please help me for how to find the file type without extension using c.(I done the file command for image using header format, now i am trying to support txt, elf, audio)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: except that only Linux has libmagic, no ?

Comment: @sakthi: what is it about the above example that doesn't answer your question ?

Comment: @sakthi if you're wanting to *reimplement* the *functionality of libmagic library in C, then the question is too broad.*

Comment: @sakthi: _Why_ do you want to implement your own `file` command from scratch? It will take an _awful_ lot of work to ensure it functions correctly in all cases, and unless you have the programming skills of the people who developed `file` / `libmagic` it's probably not a good idea to roll your own version for serious use. I guess it's a worthwhile project as a learning exercise, or if you only need to deal with a limited range of file types.

Comment: @Antti Haapala: Thank you . Now i am change my question.

Comment: @PM 2Ring: I am try to break the file command, then got the knowledge. previous i done the image using header format(it show the image highet and width).